# Find all file details in a `Logical Volume`

Tags: centos, rhel

I'm using `lvs` and `vgroot-lvroot` (mounted on `/`) is getting full.

I wonder which files are located on `vgroot-lvroot`, so I can delete some to free `vgroot-lvroot`.

I tried to use du, but found sum of the usage under `/` is less than 3.5G (Used).

Anybody who can give some solutions?

Thanks very much.

[image]

Comment: don't post a screenshot when text will do.  copy the text from your terminal and paste it into your question.  use the `{}` icon to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
 sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +1000k -mtime -20 -ls
```

for example, to find files bigger than 1000 kibibytes that changed in the last 20 days. The `-xdev` keeps you on the / partition. Obviously, you must not delete these files, but perhaps you will find some large log or cache you can cleanup. You most likely will have to remove a package. You can get the size of each rpm with

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{SIZE} %{NAME}\n' | sort -nr | less
```